# If you use Intel Rapid Storage for RAID1 on Linux server, how would you know 1 SSD is failing?

Tags: linux, monitoring, hardware-raid

I use the motherboard's RAID1 to mirror the 2 SSD, in Linux server it see only 1 'Intel Volume1,' in times where 1 SSD fail how would I know?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to know the underlying device status/hierarchy without using a tools that can talk to a RAID driver.

For example if you use MegaSAS RAID controllers, Linux only recognizes "sda", and to see details you have to use special tool called megacli.

So, you have to either turn off your motherboard RAID and use linux mdraid, in which case you will be able to see see the status of devices by running:

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

or you must find some util that can read a status from your motherboard raid controller.

Which RAID controller are we talking about here?

Intel Rapid Storage uses dmraid under linux, so you can see details by running:

```
# dmraid -s
```

To see which devices are listed as part of raid set, run:

```
# dmraid -r
```

Your RAID device will probably be listed under /dev/dm-X which will be linked from something like /dev/mapper/isw_*, so take a look at that too.

Comment: Using the Intel Rapid Storage RAID 1 feature

Comment: I've edited my answer regarding your question.

Comment: Great, the dmraid -s gives the status. I wonder if there's a way to make a script to get this status and put on CRON?

Comment: That's easy, what do you want your cron job to do? Email status to you every day?

Comment: Email when status of the RAID is not ok. But it will check daily.